# IF THEN expression in PHP function fwrite

Tags: php, if-statement

How to put IF THEN expression in PHP function `fwrite`? The below-given code does not work correctly. Please look at the line `fwrite($fh, "$row[0]...)`.

```
    $myFile = "testFile.php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    fwrite($fh, "lat    lon title   description iconOffset  icon\n");
    foreach ($result4 as $row):
        fwrite($fh, "$row[0]    $row[1] $row[2] Resource average speed is: $row[3] km/h -10,-10 if($row[4]==0) images/markerRed.png else images/markerGreen.png\n");
    endforeach;

    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$image = ($row[4] == 0) ? "images/markerRed.png" : "images/markerGreen.png";
/* ... $row[3] ... ".$image."\n"; */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($result4 as $row) 
{
    $s = "$row[0]    $row[1] $row[2] Resource average speed is: $row[3] km/h -10,-10 ";
    $s .= $row[4]==0 ? 'images/markerRed.png' : 'images/markerGreen.png';
    fwrite($fh, $s."\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` is not going to understand or evaluate PHP logic.  Separate out the `if` statement like this:

```
fwrite($fh, "$row[0]    $row[1] $row[2] Resource average speed is: $row[3] km/h -10,-10");
if($row[4]==0)
    fwrite($fh, " images/markerRed.png\n");
else
    fwrite($fh, " images/markerGreen.png\n");
```